# Extract a number from fasta read headers

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta

I am interested to extract the number "4677450" from the fasta file bellow, and put it into a variable. My code works, however it looks very ugly. I want to learn more efficient ways to do this. Could somebody teach me how?

```
>gi|47118301|dbj|BA000007.2| (4677450 - 4678851) 
AAACATCTCCCTGAACCGTTCCGCATTCGTGTTATTGAGCCAGTAAAACGTACCACTCGCGCTTATCGTG AAGAGGCAATTATTAAATCCGGTATGAACCCGTTCCTGCTGGATAGCGAAGATG
```

Comment: could you post your code? That would help to improve it;). And what do you mean by extracting the number "4677450", could you clarify please?

Comment: You're missin `>` from the start of the header if this is indeed a fasta file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page) to get the description of the read, and then parse it with a regex.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import re
with open(fasta_path, 'rb') as fin:
    s = SeqIO.parse(fin, 'fasta')
    for r in s:
        num_you_want = int(re.findall('\((\d+) - \d+\)', r.description)[0])
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. Could you explain to me what does "rb" do?

Comment: @LumRamabaja it's just the file open mode. r is for read, b for binary. see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for more details